# Is there a way to wrap an entire javascript so it only runs on a specific HTML ID?

Tags: javascript, html

I have inherited a third party Javascript - it's about 7000 lines when de-minified - that I need to use to open and close a panel of content when a link is clicked. It works fine when I import the HTML and js file to a content module in my CMS (DNN) but has the unfortunate side effect of breaking the bootstrap hamburger menu when the page is viewed on a mobile device.

I have neither the time nor JS skill to work out exactly how 7000 lines of script work, which bits I actually need and then adjust them so they only do what I need them to and not impact on the menu.

What I am hoping is that there is some way I can wrap the entire script so that it only applies to a specific area of the HTML and not to the menu area. I can easily assign an ID to the div that contains the code where I want it to operate.

So is there was way to do this - a way of testing at the start of the script that the current element matches the ID I assign, if it does then enable all functions in the entire script and if not then do nothing?

Update after reading initial replies...
The offending code can be seen at https://dnnplaypen.epicservices.com.au/application 
The JS file (unminified version) can be found at https://dnnplaypen.epicservices.com.au/portals/0/scripts/main.unmin.js   - I believe it may in fact be a complete BootStrap JS implementation which possibly explains the conflict.
and this is the relevant section of the HTML...

```html
<a href="#MemberTypes" class="btn btn-link" data-toggle="collapse" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="MemberTypes">View them.</a></p>
<div id="MemberTypes" class="collapse">
<p style="margin-left:20px;"><img src="/portals/0/Images/OrangeDot.png"> &nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold">Civil Intrastructure (CIM) Entrant</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:40px;">(Works in the civil industry and either supervises 1 or more people or has a civil university qualification e.g. leading hands, site supervisors, engineers, project managers, CEOs)</p>
<p style="margin-left:40px;">You’ll answer some questions about your qualification & employment details to confirm your eligibility.</p>
<p style="margin-left:20px;"><img src="/portals/0/Images/OrangeDot.png"> &nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold">Student</span></p>
<p style="margin-left:40px;">(Studying civil-related course at university at least 50% of the time)</p><p style="margin-left:40px;">Please have current enrolment document(s) as evidence.</p>
<p style="margin-left:20px;"><img src="/portals/0/Images/OrangeDot.png"> &nbsp;<span style="font-weight:bold">Affiliate</span></p><p style="margin-left:40px;">i.e. Part of the supply chain servicing the industry</p>
</div>
```

Any assistance in identifying which part of the JS is invoked when the link is clicked would be much appreciated.

Comment: A script doesn't "apply" to any part of the HTML. It just runs and makes whatever changes it wants to the DOM. There's no way to say "this part of the DOM is off limits".

Comment: Unfortunately there's no simple answer for this without seeing code. If you have 7000 lines of code, it is quite certainly not something that can just be "wrapped" and all applied to one element. There will be a lot of logic throughout the code that does all sorts of things.

Comment: If you can't post example code, try examining the HTML of the elemens you want to fix and then search inside the JS code for the code that selects those DOM nodes using classes, IDs, tag names, attributes.

Comment: remove the bootstrap, write your own code.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly.

First, opening and closing an element on a click shouldn't take even 7 lines of code, let alone 7000. Refusing to look into that code is dereliction. Just throwing it into an app without knowing what it does is irresponsible.

Second, your best bet may be to use DevTools to trace the click event. In Chrome you open the Sources panel, and in Firefox you open the Debugger panel. On the right side, near the top, there is a pause icon. Click that, then click the part of the webpage that toggles the content. If you're lucky, the debugger will halt execution on the first statement in the toggle codepath, which you can and should step through.

Third, the strategy we'll use is to wrap the entire block of code inside a function that exposes a fake version of the DOM API. This 7k block of mystery code is ultimately using some of the basic DOM methods to identify and manipulate the relevant elements. Your goal will be to create a fake version of that API that *only* returns the specific element you care about. You'll add an ID or other identifying attribute to the element in question, and then return that element whenever the mystery code invokes your API (which it will *think* is the real API).

Here is a simple example:

```js
// first, get our hands on the one element you want the mystery code to see
const elementThatShouldToggle = document.getElementById('target-element')

// second, construct an object that provides methods with the same names as what the real document provides
const fakeDOM = {
    // normally, document.getElementById takes an argument
    // your fake version will ignore that arg and just return the content el
    getElementById: () => elementThatShouldToggle,
    
    // you may need to mock several DOM accessor methods
    querySelector: () => elementThatShouldToggle,
    querySelectorAll: () => [elementThatShouldToggle]
}

// third: wrap the mystery code in a function that uses variable shadowing to obscure the real DOM, substituting your fake DOM instead

(function sandbox(document) {
    /* paste the 7000 lines of mystery code here */
})(fakeDOM)
```

There are drawbacks to this approach:

- You'll need to create fake versions of every DOM method that the mystery code uses; this will require you to run the app several times and look for exceptions. For every exception, you'll need to study the stack trace to identify any DOM methods that are implicated, and then create mocks that return safe values.
- If the mystery code uses the same DOM methods as the code you like, your fake API implementations will have to be a little smarter. You may need to set up branching behavior in your fake methods that return the real elements in some cases, and safe values for all other cases. Again, this will be a guess-and-test affair.
- Once the mystery code has its hands on a real DOM node, it can use the API on that node to access the entire rest of the document. It's probably not an evolving threat, so it's probably enough to then also mock the DOMNode API on the element that you provide to the mystery code.
- There may be calls inside the mystery code that does scary or bad things but without using the APIs that you're studying. If you do nothing to detect or prevent that, then the bad stuff will happen, and injecting this code into your app will inject the bad stuff, too.

How will you know when you've done enough guessing and testing? Well, because you refuse to study the 7000 lines of code, there's really no way to be sure. For all we know, there's a `setTimeout` buried in there that does something really interesting after 45 minutes. The only way to figure that out would be to wait for 45 minutes.

With this mocking strategy, it is *guaranteed* that you will write far more new code than if you just wrote your own toggle script. This is hard mode. It will be complicated, tedious, brittle, and even after all of that it will not provide the guarantee that you want.

---

A better approach would be to use the debugger to study the codepath that gets invoked on click, and then extract that code or write a replacement. Toggling some content is generally a near-trivial task. If you need help doing that, there are countless tutorials online, no doubt including some Q&As here on SO.